# How to Minimize a problem with a big number of variables?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Here is a  problem from math folklore.
Minimize $$\sum_{j=1}^{j=n} x_j$$
under the constraints
$$x_1+x_2\ge 1,\, x_2+x_3\ge 2,\dots,x_n+x_1 \ge n .$$
The Mathematica codes

```
Minimize[{Sum[x[j], {j, 1, n}],Table[x[j] + x[j + 1] >= j, {j, 1, n - 1}], x[n] + x[1] >= n},Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]]
```

and

```
Minimize[{Sum[x[j],{j, 1, n}], Table[x[j] + x[j + 1] >= j, {j, 1, n - 1}], x[n] + x[1] >= n,Table[x[j] >= 0, {j, 1, n}]}, Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]]
```

crack  it for  values of $n$ of order several hundreds,
e.g. for $n=1234$ both codes produce the value $381306$ for the objective function,
but slowly.

In fact, this is a linear programming
problem. Is it possible to solve it for $n=2019$ in Mathematica (maybe, calling external sources)?

Comment: Have you tried `LinearProgramming`?

Comment: @MrPuh: Thank you for the idea. No. Up to the documentation "If f and cons are linear or polynomial, Minimize will always find a global minimum ", I think Minimize refers to LinearProgramming itself.

Comment: For $n=2019$ the first code produces $1019595$ and `{x[1] -> 505, x[2] -> -504, x[3] -> 506, x[4] -> -503,...,x[2019] -> 1514}` in more than hour.

Comment: @MrPuh: Trying to use `LinearProgramming`, I meet the problem with creating the matrix.

Comment: For $ n=2019$ the second code produces `{1020099, {x[1] -> 1009, x[2] -> 0, x[3] -> 2, x[4] -> 1, ..., x[2019] -> 1010}}` in 4350.85 sec

Comment: `LinearOptimization` is not faster than `Minimize`. I think `Minimize` switсhes to `LinearOptimization` automatically.

Comment: It can be shown, that for all odd n, the GreaterEqual `>= `  in the conditions reduces to Equal. Then you can use `Minimize ` as a LinearProgramming routine, not explicitly searching for the sum. which is 15 times faster. `oddmi[n_] := (om = 
   Minimize[{1, Table[x[j] + x[j + 1] == j, {j, 1, n - 1}], 
     x[n] + x[1] == n}, Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]]; 
  Sum[(x[j] /. om[[2]]), {j, 1, n}]) `  and `oddmi[2019] // AbsoluteTiming ` yields `{67.8842914, 1019595} ` in 67 seconds.

Comment: @Akku14 "_It can be shown, that for all odd n, the GreaterEqual >=  in the conditions reduces to Equal._": How do you show that?

Comment: There is a breakpoint at n=201 where `LinearProgramming` and `LinearOptimization` become much slower (~50x), not sure why.

Comment: To @anderstood  Maybe this sentence is a bit too daring, but i found it empirically for all n (a lot of) i tested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
n = 2019;
c = Table[1, n];
m = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 1, Band[{1, 2}] -> 1, {n, 1} -> 1}, {n, n}];
b = Range[n];
LinearOptimization[N[c], {m, -b}, "PrimalMinimumValue"] // AbsoluteTiming // DecimalForm
(* {0.0275781, 1019595.} *)
```

Note that the use of `N` to force machine precision is important, otherwise the result will be exact but much slower.  For some reason, the slowdown becomes much more significant at `n = 201`:

```
           Exact   Approximate
n = 200    0.35 s     0.002 s
n = 201    8.9 s      0.002 s
```

---

Using `LinearProgramming` gives the same results (and has the same timing issue):

```
Total @ LinearProgramming[N[c], m, b, -∞] // AbsoluteTiming // DecimalForm
(* {0.0286999, 1019595.} *)
```

Note the `-∞`, without it the constraint `x ≥ 0` is added.

Comment: It looks like `LinearProgramming` has two methods that only work with machine precision numbers and are much faster than the ones that work for arbitrary precision.

Comment: +1. Thank you. This is a modified approach by Ulrich Neumann. How about the values of the variables? Your phrase "Note the -∞, without it the constraint x ≥ 0 is added" is unclear to me: the constraints imply (by addition) that the target function is greater than $\frac {n(n+1)} 4$.

Comment: Loking in the documentation, I got " Note the -∞, without it the constraint x ≥ 0 is added".

Comment: Having executed `LinearOptimization[N[c], {m, -b}] // AbsoluteTiming`, I see the optimal values of the variables.

Answer (score 7):

Using a different approach: guess the sequence. Then the answer for 2019 returns the right result in 20 microseconds. However, it does not prove that the sequence is the actual answer.

```
sol = ParallelTable[{n, Minimize[{Sum[x[j], {j, 1, n}], 
      Table[x[j] + x[j + 1] >= j, {j, 1, n - 1}], x[n] + x[1] >= n}, 
     Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]]}, {n, 2, 50}];

f = FindSequenceFunction[sol[[All, 2, 1]]];
answer[n_] = f[n - 1];
(* 1/8 (-1)^(-1 + n) (-1 + 5 (-1)^(-1 + n) + 2 (-1)^(-1 + n) (-1 + n)) n *)

answer[2019]
(* 1019595 *)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `1/8 (-1)^(-1 + n) (-1 + 5 (-1)^(-1 + n) + 
    2 (-1)^(-1 + n) (-1 + n)) /. n -> 1234` performs $309$, whereas the correct answer is $381306$. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @user64494 Try `answer[1234]`... You did not copy paste properly (missing `n` at the end).

Comment: Sorry, my bad. `1/8 (-1)^(-1 + n) (-1 + 5 (-1)^(-1 + n) + 
    2 (-1)^(-1 + n) (-1 + n)) n /. n -> 1234` performs `381306`. The answer is of order $\frac {n^2} 4$.

Comment: I'd like to add the formula $$\frac{1}{8} (-1)^{n-1} \left(2 (-1)^{n-1} (n-1)^2+8 (-1)^{n-1} (n-1)+3 (-1)^{n-1}-3\right)$$ in the case of nonnegative variables.

Comment: My suggestion is to apply [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) to prove the formulas.

Answer (score 5):

`NMinimize` calculates the case `n==2019`

```
 mini[n_] :=NMinimize[{Sum[x[j], {j, 1, n}],Table[x[j] + x[j + 1] >= j, {j, 1, n - 1}], x[n] + x[1] >= n},Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]][[1]]
 
 mini[2019] // Rationalize // AbsoluteTiming
 (*{0.118309, 1019595}*)
```

in `.11 seconds`!

Comment: +1. Nice and useful.

Comment: However, the results of `mini2[n_] := 
 NMinimize[{Sum[x[j], {j, 1, n}], 
    Table[x[j] + x[j + 1] >= j, {j, 1, n - 1}], x[n] + x[1] >= n}, 
   Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]][[2]]`, e.g.  `mini2[1234] // Rationalize // AbsoluteTiming` which performs `{0.130057, {x[1] -> -3.72396*10^14, x[2] -> 3.72396*10^14, ...,x[1234] -> 3.72396*10^14 }}` (most of values are as the last) are doubtful.

Comment: Maybe, `WorkingPrecision` should be increased.